# XDebug on Eclipse PHP problems

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, xdebug, eclipse-pdt

I´m starting working with PHP on Eclipse and I´m having a bad time with XDebugger. This is my first time setting up this enrironment...

I´m running Eclipse 3.8.1 with PHP Development Tools SDK (I have also C++ installed on this Eclipse).

I´ve followed the instruction from [the official xdebug site](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) to install XDebug. It seens to be installed fine, as we can see from a `phpinfo()` call:

[image]

Well, once installed, I go to Eclipse, insert my breakpoints on the code, configure the debug configuration and when I call `Debug As->PHP Web Application` all I get is an empty window on Firefox with the following link:

```
http://localhost/myproject/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=14380396300041
```

Absolutely nothing happens neither to Eclipse or on Firefox.

Here is my configuation for debugging:

[image]

PS: I haven´t installed anything related to ZEND. Is it necessary ? Here is a error I get when using the Zend Debugger option:

[image]

Help appreciated!!! Hope this will be basic learning for solving...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug on zend debugger, you need zend debugger installed.

For xdebug remote debugging (browser run) you have to enable dbgp protocol:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug#Configuration